# Specific intersections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, intersect

I have a polygon layer that looks like this i.e. they overlap.

[image: Input data]

When I run an intersection between the layers, I get more polylines i.e. for the circle on the top, the three lines get split because of the circle on the bottom. So, I get the following output for the top 3 lines

[image: Intersection issue]

So, the lines are split into 6 parts. I would like the intersection to be not be affected by overlapping polygons. Only what is contained in the polygon must be obtained as the output without the feature being split because of nearby polygons.

Is this even possible by intersection or is there another way to achieve this?

I don't really want to dissolve the polygons because I depend on FID for further processing.

Comment: Dissolve the polygons using dissolve tool first the use it to clip the lines using clip tool.

Comment: I did think about this but I am kind of dependent on the ORIG_FID of each circle!

Comment: This is why you should never do anything which is dependent on an FID column.

Comment: Create a model and use a Feature Selection Iterator to loop over each polygon and do the intersection independently.

Comment: Are you really using ArcGIS 10.0 or a later version?

Comment: I use ArcMap 10.7